# Why does the simplest example of patch creation not work?

Tags: diff, return-code

How can

```
echo "a" > a
echo "b" > a.new
diff -u a a.new > a.patch
patch -u -p1 < a.patch
```

fail at the `diff` command with return code `1` and no output?

Comment: Not sure if you could consider that not work. Also you would need to run "set -e" for it to "not work". Not sure how this q/a is helpful to others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`diff` returns `1` if differences are found (see [What are the error exit values for diff?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6971284/what-are-the-error-exit-values-for-diff) for more info on return codes) even if `stdout` is redirected into a file which isn't overly helpful in my point of view.