# Compare two files with Ansible

Tags: ansible

I am struggling to find out how to compare two files. Tried several methods including this one which errors out with:

> ***FAILED! => {"msg": "The module diff was not found in configured module paths. Additionally, core modules are missing. If this is a
>   checkout, run 'git pull --rebase' to correct this problem."}***

Is this the best practice to compare two files and ensure the contents are the same or is there a better way?

Thanks in advance.

My playbook:

```
- name: Find out if cluster management protocol is in use
      ios_command:
        commands:
          - show running-config | include ^line vty|transport input
      register: showcmpstatus
 - local_action: copy content="{{ showcmpstatus.stdout_lines[0] }}" dest=/poc/files/{{ inventory_hostname }}.result
    - local_action: diff /poc/files/{{ inventory_hostname }}.result /poc/files/transport.results
      failed_when: "diff.rc > 1"
      register: diff
 - name: debug output
      debug: msg="{{ diff.stdout }}"
```

Comment: Did you trying using the linux diff command?

Comment: I am using the diff command. I have to preface the task with local_action as the host I am running this against isn't Linux.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Why not using `stat` to compare the two files?
Just a simple example:

```
- name: Get cksum of my First file
  stat:
    path : "/poc/files/{{ inventory_hostname }}.result"
  register: myfirstfile

- name: Current SHA1
  set_fact:
    mf1sha1: "{{ myfirstfile.stat.checksum }}"

- name: Get cksum of my Second File (If needed you can jump this)
  stat:
    path : "/poc/files/transport.results"
  register: mysecondfile

- name: Current SHA1
  set_fact:
    mf2sha1: "{{ mysecondfile.stat.checksum }}"

- name: Compilation Changed
  debug:
    msg: "File Compare"
  failed_when:  mf2sha1 != mf1sha1
```

Comment: Note: the final line should be:  failed_when:  mf2sha1 != mf1sha1

Comment: if the two files are empty, Using stat.checksum will skip in the playbook.
The best option is to use the command module with diff

Answer (score 2):

your "diff" task is missing the `shell` keyword, Ansible thinks you want to use the `diff` module instead.

also i think `diff` (as name of the variable to register the tasks result) leads ansible to confusion, change to `diff_result` or something.

code (example):

```
  tasks:
  - local_action: shell diff /etc/hosts /etc/fstab
    failed_when: "diff_output.rc > 1"
    register: diff_output

  - debug:
      var: diff_output
```

hope it helps

Comment: shouldn't the third line be "failed_when: "diff_output.rc > 0"?

Comment: 0 is returned when files are same and 1 when they are not. so `diff_output.rc > 1` means that we will throw error when diff throwed an error.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6971284/what-are-the-error-exit-values-for-diff

Answer (score 1):

A slightly shortened version of 'imjoseangel' answer which avoids setting facts:

```
  vars:
    file_1: cats.txt
    file_2: dogs.txt

  tasks:
  - name: register the first file
    stat:
      path: "{{ file_1 }}"
      checksum: sha1
      get_checksum: yes
    register: file_1_checksum

  - name: register the second file
    stat:
      path: "{{ file_2 }}"
      checksum: sha1
      get_checksum: yes
    register: file_2_checksum

  - name: Check if the files are the same
    debug: msg="The {{ file_1 }} and {{ file_2 }} are identical"
    failed_when: file_1_checksum.stat.checksum != file_2_checksum.stat.checksum
    ignore_errors: true
```

Answer (score 1):

From Ansible User Guide: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html

```
- name: Fail task when both files are identical
  ansible.builtin.raw: diff foo/file1 bar/file2
  register: diff_cmd
  failed_when: diff_cmd.rc == 0 or diff_cmd.rc >= 2
```