# How to get the exit code of Vimdiff command which gives the result of whether the two compared files were same or not?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, exit-code, vimdiff

For diff command, an exit status of 0 means no differences were found, 1 means some differences were found.

[What are the error exit values for diff?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6971284/what-are-the-error-exit-values-for-diff)

It works as expected with diff command.

However, when I try the same with vimdiff command, it doesn't work.

```
vimdiff -c "set foldlevel=9999" file1.log file2.log -c TOhtml -c  'w! 'vimdiff.html'' -c 'qa!'
```

Even though file1 and file2 are different here, `echo $?` returns 0.
For diff, it returns 1 successfully as the files are different.

Is there a way I can do the same for vimdiff? How can I know whether the files were same or different for the above vimdiff command?

Comment: But why would you want to use `vmdiff` which is not designed to work that way instead of `diff` which does exactly as required?

Comment: vimdiff has features to output colored diff with side-by-side comparison which i can easily port to an html file.

Comment: Can you use `mydiff=$(vimdiff ...); if [ -n "${mydiff}" ]; then ...` ?

Comment: I did some thinking and research on this one and I can't come up with anything good unless you want to be writing Vimscript. Personally, I would just run a second `diff` command.